# Renderer Bring to front highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to put the renderer.label to front so that it wont be covered by a plotline label ? see image below 
[image]

```
      plotbandLabel = this.renderer.label(
          (66).toFixed(2),
          chart.plotLeft + chart.plotWidth,
          yAxis.toPixels(66) - labelOffset,
          'rect'
        )
        .css({
          'color': '#FFFFFF',
          'z-index':'999'
        }).attr({
          align: 'right',
          fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
          padding: 8,
          zIndex: 999
        })
        .add();

        yAxis.addPlotLine({
                    value: 55,
                    color: 'blue',
                    width: 3,
                    dashStyle: 'Solid',
                    zIndex: 1,
                    id: 'ahLine',
                            label: {
        text: 'testing',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        align: 'right',
        rotation: 0,
        useHTML: true,
        zIndex: 1,
        style: {
            "padding": "0 10px 0 0",
            "background-color": "#ffa500",//#CF2323",
            "color": "white",
            "height": "25px",
            "text-align": "center",
            "padding-top": "5px",
            "border-radius": "5px",
            "z-index":"1"
        }
    }

                });
```

Here is my sample code http://jsfiddle.net/eb9mjc2j/
Appreciate your help on this. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The reason why this is happening is because of how Highcharts visualizations are rendered. The way I understand it, adding items using the `renderer` method create HTML elements that are separate from the chart, whereas other chart elements, such as the "testing" label added to your plot line, are rendered in SVG format. Because they effectively live in two worlds, you'll never be able to arrange them the way you want using z-index. SVG always wins.

It looks like you were already on the right track with some commented code in your fiddle. I uncommented the section you had here:

```
      markerLabel = this.renderer.label(
        (55).toFixed(2),
        chart.plotLeft + chart.plotWidth,
        yAxis.toPixels(55) - labelOffset,
        'rect'
      )
        .css({
        color: 'white'
      }).attr({
        align: 'right',
        fill: 'red',
        padding: 8,
        zIndex: 997
      })
        .add();
```

Next, I commented out the label on the plot line (the orange "testing" box).

```
      yAxis.addPlotLine({
        value: 55,
        color: 'blue',
        width: 3,
        dashStyle: 'Solid',
        zIndex: 1,
        id: 'ahLine'/*,
                              label: {
          text: 'testing',
          verticalAlign: 'middle',
          align: 'right',
          rotation: 0,
          useHTML: true,
          zIndex: 1,
          style: {
              "padding": "0 10px 0 0",
              "background-color": "#ffa500",//#CF2323",
              "color": "white",
              "height": "25px",
              "text-align": "center",
              "padding-top": "5px",
              "border-radius": "5px",
              "z-index":"1"
          }
      }*/

      });
```

Then, to make sure this second rendered label stays put, I added two items to your y-axis so the maximum value is always 100. This will keep your chart from shifting in height and prevent the label from getting offset from your chosen value of 55.

```
yAxis: [{
  opposite: false,
  title: {
    enabled: false
  }, 
  max: 100, /* keep the chart's height from changing with each new point */
  showLastLabel: true /* show 100 in the axis labels; this is false by default in Highstock */
}],
```

Here's a revised version of your fiddle with these changes: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/eb9mjc2j/4/.

I hope this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can render another custom path and label. This way you can control their placement with `zIndex` property. You could also try to place HTML label before SVG.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/fbohy9od/